# Expectation of a function of uniform random variables

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, uniform-distribution

Given IID random variables $X,Y\sim U[0,\mu]$, I am trying to find the below expectation

$$
\mathbb{E}_{X,Y} \left[\frac{(X-s_1)^m}{(X-s_1)^m+(Y-s_2)^m} \right]
$$

where $s_1,s_2,m$ are constants (for simplicity, one can consider $m=1$). Can anyone give hints about how to think about this? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, welcome, have you tried something? What was your approach like?

Comment: Double integral ($0,\mu$ in both coordinates) over expression as function of x and y.

Comment: What does the notation $E_{X,Y}$ mean?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}_{X,Y}$ is standard notation for the expectation over random variables $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @Nicholas E:  Are you *sure* this is the function you want?  After all, for $m=1$ there will be points at which the denominator vanishes, so the contribution will be infinite.

Comment: @David G. Stork Would not the denominator taking the value 0 have probability 0?

Comment: Yes... but I nevertheless think the integral diverges.